# Nesting of font switches is not working in Fontspec

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, small-caps

I am using `fontspec` in LuaLaTeX (TeX Live 2022 in Overleaf). After defining a font family `\nounfont` containing small caps (both medium and bold), I intend to create the font switch `\textnoun` (for proper nouns), via the command `\DeclareTextFontCommand\textnoun{\nounfont\scshape}`. However, the following test code shows that the `\textbf` switch acts on the small caps font only when applied *inside* the custom font switch:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\nounfont{texgyretermes}[
SmallCapsFeatures = { Letters = SmallCaps } ,
]

%\newfontfamily\nounfont{TexGyrePagellaX}[
%SmallCapsFeatures = { Letters = SmallCaps }
%] % same issue

\DeclareTextFontCommand\textnoun{\nounfont}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\textnoun{\textsc{Norma Cenva}}}'s nesting does not work.

\textbf{\textsc{\textnoun{Pantagruel}}}'s nesting is not working either.

\textnoun{\textbf{\textsc{Julia Bowman}}}'s nesting works!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there some way to define the new font in such a way that the corresponding font switch correctly works (in any order) with any other font switches?

Comment: set up a main font, e.g. `\setmainfont{latinmodernroman}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I cannot do that because I am using a custom class (not included in the example in order to keep it "minimal").

Comment: well then try `\DeclareFontShape{TU}{lmr}{bx}{sc}{<-> \UnicodeFontFile{lmromancaps10-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures;embolden=4;}}{}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It didn't work (BTW, your first solution works fine; unfortunately, I cannot resort to it). Thanks anyway.

Comment: try `\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{\bfdefault}`

Comment: Although I am using a different, custom document class, with many different codes, I do use `fontspec` and have a similar situation when nesting. Solution: The class documentation says, "nest this way, not that way." Problem solved, for anyone who reads my docs.